Graph Powershell adding a user to PIM for a privileged security group
I have seen several articles online, but I do not think it is for what I need. I am looking for a Graph cmdlet in Powershell to add a user to PIM for a privileged security group, like what is done in Entra below. This is from the security group's page in Entra:


I found this documentation of possible cmdlets, but the naming of them is pretty confusing. Does anybody know which cmdlet is the one I need?
Thanks!

Could you confirm whether your requirement is to add user to member or owner role https://i.imgur.com/6hD9OlF.png?

It is for a member

Yes, I gave script for member only. Please check the answer and let me know if it works : )

To add user to PIM for privileged security group via Microsoft Graph PowerShell, you can make use of below sample script:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'PrivilegedEligibilitySchedule.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup'

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance

$currentUtcStartTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
$expirationDateTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")

$params = @{
    accessId = "member"  # Set to 'member' for regular membership; use 'owner' for admin privileges
    principalId = "userId"  # User's Object ID
    groupId = "groupId"  # Replace with the Security Group's Object ID
    action = "AdminAssign"  
    scheduleInfo = @{
        startDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse($currentUtcStartTime)  # Set to current UTC date and time
        expiration = @{
            type = "AfterDateTime"  # Specify the expiration type
            endDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse($expirationDateTime)  # Set expiration to 2 hours from now
        }
    }
    justification = "Assign eligible request."  # Provide a justification for the assignment
}

New-MgIdentityGovernancePrivilegedAccessGroupEligibilityScheduleRequest -BodyParameter $params

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where user is assigned to member role for PIM security group:

Reference:
Create eligibilityScheduleRequest - Microsoft Graph v1.0

Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. I could not get that cmdlet to work but I just used Invoke-RestMethod on "/identityGovernance/privilegedAccess/group/eligibilityScheduleRequests" and its working great. Thank you for the help!

@Glad to be of help
